# EmojiAppCompatTextView displays emojis with a grey tint

Tags: android, android-support-library

When I use `EmojiAppCompatTextView` from `android-EmojiCompat`and add any emoji to it. It shows that emoji with a light grey tint over it.

Answer (score 1):

use `android:textColor=@android:color/black`